# How to use global SASS variables in my Nuxt 3 components

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Nuxt 3 first Release Candidate will be launched very soon, so I am starting a fresh new project with Nuxt 3. I am already facing an usual issue, and I was about to ask how to solve it. But I managed to do it by myself, so I am making a Self Answered question, in order to help people that might face the same issue in the futur.

How to use global Sass (or Scss) variables in my vue components ? I saw on other posts that we can use the `@nuxtjs/style-resources` package, but it seems like a Nuxt 2 package. And I think there might be a better way to do it in Nuxt 3 **without adding dependencies** like `style-resources` ?

What I mean by "global variable" is a SASS variable is that I want to be able to use the SASS variable in any of my Vue components, without having to include SASS files.

#### What I want

(Given that I already installed the `sass` package)

```css
// @/assets/style/main.sass
$grey-bg: #CCC
$light-blue: #c6d8f5
```

```html
<!-- app.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtWelcome />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass">
body
  background-color: $grey-bg
  color: $light-blue
</style>
```

#### What I already tried

I tried to include my sass file in the [Nuxt config CSS](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt.config#css) property like this :

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt3"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ["@/assets/style/global.sass"]
})
```

And it work in the way that the style in my `global.sass` file will be applied in my entire application. But it does not work in the way that if I refer to a variable in my SASS file from a Vue Component, the build fails with this error :

`Plugin: vite:css. Error: Undefined variable.`

Answer (score 17):

In Nuxt 3, Vite will come out of the box, wich was not the case in Nuxt 2. Since Nuxt 3 then, we can put the vite config by default in the `nuxt.config.ts` file (refering to [the documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets#global-styles-imports)).

Wich means we can simply add a Vite preprocessorOptions additionalData property in the nuxt config :

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt3"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                sass: {
                    additionalData: '@import "@/assets/style/global.sass"',
                },
            },
        },
    },
})
```

And I can also split my global SASS in different files. All the variables declared in any of those files will be available in all my components :

- @/assets/style/global.sass
- @/assets/style/_animations.sass
- @/assets/style/_colors.sass
- @/assets/style/_fonts.sass

```css
// global.sass
@import "animations", "colors", "fonts"
```

Remember, we need to have the `sass` package install for that to work. If it is not already installed, run one of the following command :

```bash
yarn add -D sass
# or
npm install -D sass
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Very odd and strange SCSS setup in nuxt / vue. Really hard to use helper classes too without ballooning the size of the style blocks, can't use @extend etc.

Comment: @v3nt Change your files from sass to scss. This setup isn't odd, but actually suggested by Nuxt themselves [here](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/assets#example-2).

Comment: thanks @Maytha8 - they already are .scss files.

Comment: I think this is slightly different now, new docs (worked for me) are here:
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this will help someone. Now it worked.
Pay attention to **';' after "@import"**. Nuxt cursed it.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
        vite: {
            css: {
                preprocessorOptions: {
                    scss: {
                        additionalData: '@import "@/assets/scss/app.scss";',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
```